# Cannot add category or custom taxonomy from admin. WordPress site is hosted in Windows 16 server via IIS. No XAMPP or WAMP

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy

I am facing a strange issue and have no clue whatsoever.

My WordPress site is running a custom theme and hosted on a Windows PC via IIS (no XAMPP or WAMP). I can save Post, Custom Post Type, also can create new User and edit those as usual.

But I simply cannot add any **Post Category** or **Custom Taxonomy** associated with the custom post type. The wheel beside **Add New Category** is spinning and nothing happens from here. And in the end, nothing gets added!

To test, I switched back to `twentytwenty` theme but the same thing is happening here as well.

I checked the database prefix. The table prefix is `yd20_`, the correct prefix is defined in `wp-config.php` (`$table_prefix`) and it has been added to `$GLOBALS` array correctly in `wp-settings.php` file.

However, one question! The prefix in the database is `yd20`, while $table_prefix in wp-config.pg is `Yd20` (**Y** is capital). I changed it to small (y), but got an error in the site. So I reverted back to what it was, i.e. capital (Y).

The screenshots below show what exactly category and taxonomy pages look like:

[image]

[image]

I am screwed up as this is a completely new kind of issue I am facing. Google could not help either.

**EDIT**

My local development environment is running Ubuntu Linux and I am facing no such problem here! This is only happening on the server and that too with Categories and Custom Taxonomies only.

**EDIT #2**

1. WordPress version: 5.3
2. Plugin Status: No active plugin.
3. Theme used: `twentytwenty`
4. Server: Windows 2016

**Console output**
[image]

**Network output**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Chrome press Ctr+Shift+I and press the "Add New Featue" button in your page. See in Console and Network for errors.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! `admin-ajax.php` is giving 403. I added the screenshots in the original question. When I access `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` the result is 0 (zero).